# delete user profile from windows vista

Tags: windows-vista

I am having problems with my emails on my local computer.

It seems the outlook.pst file is corrupted. I am using windows vista as the OS. I read that if I delete the profile in control panel and delete the outlook.pst file and re-login, the system will automatically create new outlook.pst file and everything should work fine. But I have lot of files saved under "My Documents" and "Desktop". so if I delete a profile, will it delete all those files?

Comment: This should be moved to serverfault.com or superuser.com

Comment: Sorry, not programming related.

Answer (score 2):

I would just delete the .PST or .OST file...  Only delete the profile in last ditch attempts...  If you delete the profile, the files may go with it if you tell it to...  Probably not safe without having some backups first.

I'm also voting to move this question to ServerFault.

Answer (score 1):

YOU won't be able to access any file under "profiles my documents" it will say access denied. Take a back up of what you want and then delete the profile you don't want. I have gone through this once. Careful bro !